# Does Google still offer free incoming/outgoing voice calls with any of their Android services?

Tags: calls, google-voice, google-hangouts, google-talk, voip

On Android, is Google still offering free incoming or outgoing voice calls to landlines/cellphones through any of their services?

It seems like they keep changing it, and everything I read has conflicting information.

Note that I'm talking specifically about VOIP to landline or cellphone, not VOIP to VOIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Most" calls to numbers in the US and Canada are free through Hangouts as long as you are also in the US/Canada. This is noted in [Google's support pages](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/6079055) and you can find all of the rates [on this page](https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/rates?hl=en&p=hangout). You need the [Hangouts Dialer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.hangoutsdialer) in order to place a call.

There is no specific listing of the US/Canada numbers that incur a charge (it's $0.01 per minute), but you you can look up the rate for any number on the [Google Voice calling credit page](https://www.google.com/voice#billing) (requires signing into your Google account).